# Getting CloudKit CKAsset URL?

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services

I'd like to share a CloudKit asset in the public database with people who aren't using my app. From the CKAsset class, there's only a `fileURL` property, which points to a local file, so no URL given.

On the documentation for CloudKit Web Services, however, [there is a "referencing existing assets" request](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference/RereferenceAssets/RereferenceAssets.html), which [in its' response](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference/Types/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015240-CH3-SW3) gives a `downloadURL` to the asset file.

Calling this from my app gives me a 421 status code, which is described [in documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference/ErrorCodes/ErrorCodes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015240-CH4-SW1) as "AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED", as it requires a `ckSession` parameter to be given, which is a "session identifier of an authenticated user". It also passes a `redirectURL`, where a user can type in their iCloud login, and then be re-directed back to the web application, now with a session identifier.

Opening this URL inside the app didn't immediately return the session identifier, but instead expected the user to go through the login process in a browser, before receiving their session ID.

This seems totally off-track, and the wrong thing to be doing. I'm certainly not going to make my users log in to iCloud through a web interface. The only thing missing for that CloudKit Web Services url is the session ID. Is there a way for me to get that using the CloudKit framework? Or is there another way for me to find out this file's URL?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apple's official CloudKit.js, here is the code to configure your CloudKit access:

```js
window.addEventListener('cloudkitloaded', function() {
  console.log('Cloudkit loaded');
  CloudKit.configure({
    locale: 'en-us',
    containers: [{
      containerIdentifier: 'iCloud.com.getYoursInXcode',
      apiTokenAuth: {
        apiToken: 'getThisInCloudkitDashboardApiAccess',
        persist: true //Set cookie
      },
      environment: 'production'
    }]
  });
  // Do your thing here

  })
```

If you are fetching records in your backend, it is still better to get your API token instead of using the Server-To-Server process.
For example, query records in GO, to fetch a record, compose your request body like this

```go
sampleRequest = []byte('{
        "resultsLimit":"4",
        "desiredKeys": ["recordTitle","recordDescription"],
        "query": {
        "recordType": "myRecord",
        "sortBy": {
        "fieldName": "rank",
        "ascending": true
    }
    }
        }')
```

And send it to the following Url

```
http.NewRequest("POST", ""https://api.apple-cloudkit.com/database/1/iCloud.com.yourIdentifier/production/public/records/query?ckAPIToken=YOURTOKEN", bytes.NewBuffer(RequestBody))
```